# Primefaces dataGrid content doesn't update after removing an item

Tags: datagrid, primefaces

I have a datagrid component:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:panelGroup id="statementDataContent" layout="block">

[... some controlls ...]

    <p:dataGrid id="dg" columns="#{statementDataRequestAction.columnCount}"  var="statement"
       value="#{statementDataRequestAction.data}"  rowIndexVar="#{statement.id}" >
          <p:column>
         <p:panelGrid columns="1" >
                 
              [... some controlls ...]
              <p:commandButton value="-" immediate="true" type="submit" actionListener="#{statementDataRequestAction.remove(statement)}"  process="@form" update="??? " />
                              
         </p:panelGrid>
          </p:column>
    </p:dataGrid>
```

As you can see, there is a button to remove the current item. It calls the bean correctly and the method removes the item from the list what backs the grid.
The datagrid even refreshes (I can see that the number of displayed columns reduces by one), but not the values inside the grid elements.

In the code, I intently wrote ??? because I tried a few dozen options, including:

- Refreshing the grid: `dg`, `:myForm:dg`, etc.
- Refreshing the whole form: `@form`, `:myForm`, `:myForm:statementDataContent`, etc.
- Refreshing the fields within, but hard to address them
- Even some exotic things, such using `p:remoteCommand` or `p:collector`*

My bean is in SessionScope (cannot change it).

And to help understanding my problem: Imagine this starting state:

[image: Before delete]

I have three items in the datagrid. Now I press the delete button of the leftmost (first) item. The logs tells that the right element is removed from the backing collection:

```
Remove statement: 4 - StatementDataWrapper [id=4, data=Entity: 16 - hu.avhga.entities.StatementData, year=1000]
===============Removed: true :
[StatementDataWrapper [id=5, data=Entity: 17 - hu.avhga.entities.StatementData, year=1010], StatementDataWrapper [id=6, data=Entity: 18 - hu.avhga.entities.StatementData, year=1020]]
```

Also, The following screenshot displays the results afterward:

[image]

As you can see, the grid now detects that there is only two items to display, but the two displayed are the first two.

Please give me some hint, because I ran out of them. :-(

Thanks in advance!

Balage

Answer (score 0):

The `p:commandButton` provided by PrimeFaces is using AJAX by default, so you should rather set `process="@none"` and not set the `immediate` flag
([Example in PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprPartialTree.jsf)).

Also using `p:commandButton` inside `p:dataTable` did not work properly but was fixed in version 3.4 (if i remember correctly). This could also apply to `p:dataGrid`.